# TypeError: registration.listener.apply is not a function

Tags: react-native

I have built a RN app with Firebase. When running it on IOS i sometimes receive this errror:
TypeError: registration.listener.apply is not a function. (In 'registration.listener.apply(registration.context, args)', 'registration.listener.apply' is undefined). 
It only sometimes appears and dismissing it will not affect the run of the app.
Does anyone know what is causing this issue and how to fix it?
My Call stack from top to bottom is:

Emit
EventEmit.js: 105:36
__callFunction
MessageQueue.js: 423:32
__guar$argument_0
MessageQueue.js: 113:26
__guard
MessageQueue.js: 367:11
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
MessageQueue.js: 112:17
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
[native code]